# addSubview insertSubview aboveSubview bit confused as to why it does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a bit confused all as to why the belowSubview does not work.

I'm adding some (subviews) to my navigationController  and all of that works well.

```
-(UITableView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

... 
...

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:ImageView];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

add some point in my app I wish to add another toolbar or image above my toolbar.

so let's say I'm doing something like this

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
    ...
    ...

        [self.navigationController.view insertSubview:NewImageView aboveSubview:toolbar];
//crucial of course [edit]
            rvController = [RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle] mainBundle];
rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;
rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];
rvController.tableDataSource = Children;
[rvController release];
```

However this doesn't work..
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here ... 
Should I have used something else instead of addSubview  or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have posted, it looks like that should work.

There are a few other issues however.  First it is convention that varibales that represent instances of objects start with lowercase.  So `ImageView` and `NewImageView` should be `imageView` and `newImageView`.

I would make sure that in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method `newImageView` and toolbar are both valid.  Are they in your header file?

Try this and see where is errors out:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
...
...
    NSAssert(self.navigationController.view,@"WTF? self.navigationController.view is nil");
    NSAssert([self.navigationController.view superview],@"WTF? lf.navigationController.view  is not onscreen");
    NSAssert(newImageView,@"WTF? newImageView is nil");
    NSAssert(toolbar,@"WTF? toolbar is nil");
    NSAssert([toolbar superview],@"WTF? toolbar is on in the view");

    [self.navigationController.view insertSubview:newImageView aboveSubview:toolbar];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction .. you were right, there is nothing wrong with I just made a slight mistake ;) which you can see in my edit.  I pushed a new viewController...

Comment: Are you trying to get your new image/toolbar above the toolbar on the original screen, or the new one that appears?  or both?